# Redux Saga action async action called once but fired twice

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

So I dispatch my redux-saga action once from my react-native app and it makes two API calls. I'm trying to figure out why this is, and how to only have it send one.

App.js

```
  const initFetch = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
    dispatch(fetchLiked({ page: 0, search: "", userToken }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initFetch();
  }, []);
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import likedReducer from "./reducers/liked";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "./sagas/rootSaga";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  liked: likedReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "primary",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

rootSaga.js

```
import { take, call, all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { watchFetchLikedSaga } from "./likedSaga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([watchFetchLikedSaga()]);
}
```

likedSaga.js

```
import { takeLatest, call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import Server from "../../utils/Server";
import { fetchLikedSuccess } from "./../actions/liked";
import { types } from "../actions/types";

function* asyncFetchLiked(data) {
  console.log("sending async fetch");
  const { page, search, userToken } = data.payload;
  try {
    const response = yield call(() =>
      Server.get("/api/titles/getliked", {
        headers: { "auth-token": userToken },
        params: { page: page, search: search },
      })
    );
    yield put(fetchLikedSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

export function* watchFetchLikedSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(types.SEND_REQUEST, asyncFetchLiked);
}
```

export const fetchLiked = (data) => {
return {
type: types.SEND_REQUEST,
payload: data,
};
};

actions/liked.js

```
export const fetchLiked = (data) => {
  console.log("fetchLiked");
  return {
    type: types.SEND_REQUEST,
    payload: data,
  };
};

export const fetchLikedSuccess = (data) => {
  console.log("fetchLikedSuccess");
  return {
    type: types.SEND_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
};

export const fetchLikedFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: types.SEND_REQUEST_FAILURE,
    payload: {},
    error: error,
  };
};
```

My console.log output looks like this. You can see the action is only being dispatched once, but it is sending two async requests and calling the reducer success action twice.

```
fetchLiked
sending async fetch
sending async fetch
fetchLikedSuccess
fetchLikedSuccess
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have accidently (due to copying or something) the same value for some other action as for types.SEND_REQUEST?

Comment: I would also check how many times the `watchFetchLikedSaga` is called in case it is run multiple times for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Martin, the problem was watchFetchLikedSaga was being called twice because my App.js was being rendered twice.